# GSON error Expected String but was found object

Tags: json, gson

Im using gson for desserialize this object:

```
[

        {
            "_id": "53357a63138c2564feaf187f",
            "worktypes": [
                {
                    "name": "Tipo uno"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tipo dos"
                },
                {
                    "name": "dasdasd"
                }
            ],
            "company": "aa"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5335d03deffb9c0000b44304",
            "company": "asasdasd"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5339ba03ef04d1c5882f7aa2",
            "company": "Nueva"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5339c150ef04d1c5882f7aa3",
            "company": "Nueva"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5339c4f1ef04d1c5882f7aa4",
            "company": "Otra mas"
        },
        {
            "_id": "53340d07d6429d27e1284c77",
            "worktypes": [
                {
                    "name": "Pompas"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name 4"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Bombillos"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Pompas"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Bombillos 2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "uevvaa"
                },
                {
                    "name": "uevvaa"
                },
                {
                    "name": "aa"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ee"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ee"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ee"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ee"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ee"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ee"
                },
                {
                    "name": "asdasd"
                }
            ],
            "company": "Company2"
        }
    ]
```

With this code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Company>>() {}.getType();
List<Company> lcs = (List<Company>) new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(value),collectionType);
```

Company contains companyString, worktypes list with worktpyes strcuture..

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare this class:

```
class Company {
    String _id;
    List<WorkType> worktypes = new ArrayList<WorkType>();
    String company;

    class WorkType {
        String name;
    }
}
```

And use this:

```
List<Company> companies = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, new TypeToken<List<Company>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: With this, generate a list of com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap' but i need Company class.

Comment: I just ran your code - it works too. What class for deserialization did you use? And in what form comes 'value'?

Comment: value is a JsonarrayObject

Comment: 'value' must be a plain text in json-form. And String.valueOf() is not necessary in this case.

Comment: And thank you for assessment and constructive criticism. Good luck!